# Generate file filled with content from a set of files with any size in a given range

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, random

Is there a way to generate a file of any size within a range (provided as input in bytes: Eg: range1=10000000 range2= 5000000000), filled with random lines from a list of files (folder provided as input) in Linux?

I tried the following to produce a big file (1 GB) (Obtained from superuser forum)

```
openssl rand -out sample.txt -base64 $(( 2**30 * 3/4 )) 
split -b 10000 -a 10 sample.txt
```

This gave me numerous files with 10K bytes from the sample.txt

But I need to tweak it (OR a better way than this in terms of performance) so it accepts my input and build based on that.

**Example:**

Folder1/file1 contains

```
sddfas|sdfsda f|dfsdg b| sdf| afsdf
asfsdf|erty|345|rty4|et64|wrt
.
.
.
regbg| f234|sgfgfg|v|||
```

Folder1/file2 contains

```
fs|dfg|hth|dvfbdgh|ryjn|cv
34t|fgsdhb|yttbvx|t8dghfr|grte|vf
.
.
.
sf vcv| ds||||
```

Output file should be

```
34t|fgsdhb|yttbvx|t8dghfr|grte|vf
asfsdf|erty|345|rty4|et64|wrt
.
.
.
sddfas|sdfsda f|dfsd
```

**Note**: Output is filled up by random lines from the first two files, and exited when it reached the file size limit (Chosen randomly from [1MB, 2MB] -- It means any size allowed between 1MB to 2MB and does not mean either 1MB or 2MB)

Comment: Why do you need random lines from existing files? What's wrong with purely random files?

Comment: @AaronDigulla I use them to test. I am trying to achieve something similar to scramble in oracle. So i need some valid but scrambled data

Comment: what is `range1` and `range2` supposed to do? Ranges always need a start and an end, not only one number.

Comment: For eg: range1=1MB range=2MB shall apply a limit to the file generated (Minimum of 1 MB and a maximum of 2MB)

Comment: So you need random lines from a set of files in a folder to get a result file which is `[1MB, 2MB]` in size?

Comment: Exactly. limit is on size and not on line count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy and fast way to generate a file with random content:

```
dd if=/dev/random of="${filename}" bs="${size}" count=1
```

If you need better randomness, you can use `/dev/urandom` but since it's not base on a pseudorandom number generator, `urandom` is much slower.

If you want N random lines from a single file, use `shuf`:

```
shuf -n "${numberOfLines}" "${filename}"
```

If you need `[X, Y]` bytes of random content from a set of files, then the command line utilities won't be enough. If you have a script language installed (Python, Perl), then write a small script which does this for you.

If "close is good enough", then you can use

```
shuf folder/* | dd if=- of=sample.txt bs=1K count=2048
```

to get a 2MB sample file which you can then shorten or invoke the command above again with different numbers for `count`

Comment: My intention is to achieve a scrambled data and not random. I tried the same using `openssl rand` as I said in my question. I agree that urandom is much slower and hence I used `openssl rand`. Also my another requirement was to have a size from a range specified

Comment: So it's not important that lines are cut off in the middle?

Comment: Not important on which line to cut. Need a file of size from a range with meaningful data from other files. So size shall control the no of lines pasted in the new file

Comment: That's what `shuf` does. Please think on what you want and explain it clearly.

Comment: Cool. I will try this and keep you posted. Thanks

Comment: Error: dd: opening `-': No such file or directory